# What is the G function of FIPS-186-2?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

We are trying to follow FIPS 186-2 for creating a  pseudo random number generator for EAP AKA AT_MAC Calculation in SIM Authentication:

1. Choose a new, secret value for the seed-key, XKEY
2. In hexadecimal notation `let t = 67452301 EFCDAB89 98BADCFE 10325476 C3D2E1F0`. This is the initial value for `H0|H1|H2|H3|H4` in the FIPS SHS [SHA-1]
3. Code:

   ```
   For j = 0 to m - 1 do
       XSEED_j = 0 /* no optional user input */
       For i = 0 to 1 do
           XVAL = (XKEY + XSEED_j) mod 2^b
           w_i = G(t, XVAL)
           XKEY = (1 + XKEY + w_i) mod 2^b
           x_j = w_0|w_1
   ```

The algorithm requires the use of function `G(t,c)`. We have gone through several SPECS but not found the correct definition of how to implement `G(t,c)`.

At one place we have seen that `G(t,c)` is the same as SHA-1 except for some padding. But, it is not very clear. ***What is the `G` function in Implementation of FIPS-186-2 for EAP AKA AT_MAC Calculation in SIM Authentication?***

Answer (score 3):

The RNG used (arguably misused) as a PRF for key derivation in [EAP-AKA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4187#section-7) and also [EAP-SIM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4186#section-7) was defined as a small almost incidental part of FIPS 186-2 (2000) plus change notice 1 (2001). The URL in the 2006 RFCs http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-2/fips186-2-change1.pdf is no longer valid, because 186-2 has been superseded by 186-3 (2009) and 186-4 (2013) and those newer versions no longer define the RNGs for digital signatures; instead they refer to a separate publication, first SP800-90 and now SP800-90A, whose focus is random generators.

However, 186-2 is still **available in the CSRC archive** at https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/archive/fips186-2/fips186-2-change1.pdf . The **original definition** of two RNGs, with two applications that both involve generating numbers less than a number called 'q' (the subgroup order for the Digital Signature Algorithm DSA), is in Appendix 3 starting on page 16 (PDF page 19):

> The algorithms employ a one-way function G(t,c), where t is 160 bits, c is b bits (160 ≤ b ≤ 512) and G(t,c) is 160 bits. One way to construct G is via [a modification of] the Secure Hash Algorithm (SHA-1), as defined in the Secure Hash Standard (SHS). The 160-bit message digest output of the SHA-1 algorithm when message M is input is denoted by SHA-1(M). A second method for constructing G is to use the Data Encryption Standard (DES). The construction of G by these techniques is discussed in sections 3.3 and 3.4 of this appendix.

> 3.1. ALGORITHM FOR [generating x<sub>0..m-1</sub>]
> Step 1. Choose a new, secret value for the seed-key, XKEY.
> Step 2. In hexadecimal notation let
>     t = 67452301 EFCDAB89 98BADCFE 10325476 C3D2E1F0
>   This is the initial value for H<sub>0</sub> || H<sub>1</sub> || H<sub>2</sub> || H<sub>3</sub> || H<sub>4</sub> in the SHS.
> Step 3. For j = 0 to m - 1 do
>   a. XSEED<sub>j</sub> = optional user input.
>   b. XVAL = (XKEY + XSEED<sub>j</sub>) mod 2<sup>b</sup>.
>   c. x<sub>j</sub> = G(t,XVAL) mod q.
>   d. XKEY = (1 + XKEY + x<sub>j</sub>) mod 2<sup>b</sup>.

However, the **change notice** at PDF page 71 first alters section 3.1 to:

> Step 1. Choose a new, secret value for the seed-key, XKEY .
> Step 2. In hexadecimal notation let
>     t = 67452301 EFCDAB89 98BADCFE 10325476 C3D2E1F0.
>   This is the initial value for H<sub>0</sub> || H<sub>1</sub> || H<sub>2</sub> || H<sub>3</sub> || H<sub>4</sub> in the SHS [FIPS 180-1].
> Step 3. For j = 0 to m - 1 do
>   3.1 XSEED <sub>j</sub> = optional user input
>   3.2 For i = 0 to 1 do
>     a. XVAL = (XKEY + XSEED <sub>j</sub>) mod 2<sup>b</sup>
>     b. w<sub>i</sub> = G(t, XVAL ).
>     c. XKEY = (1 + XKEY + w<sub>i</sub>) mod 2<sup>b</sup> .
>   3.3 x<sub>j</sub> = (w<sub>0</sub> || w<sub>1</sub>) mod q

and then adds that this algorithm can be used for 'General Purpose Random Number Generation' by removing the 'mod q' term from the computation of x<sub>j</sub>.

You can see **this is now the algorithm you quote** from Appendix A of rfc4187 (and Appendix B of rfc4186) except those set XSEED<sub>j</sub> to zero (as stated in section 7 of each RFC) and change the notation because RFCs are ASCII-text (`|` for concatenation, `^` for superscript/exponentiation, and `_` for subscript).

You want the **G function based on SHA-1** specified in 3.3:

> G(t,c) may be constructed using steps (a) - (e) in section 7 of the Specifications for the Secure Hash Standard. Before executing these steps, {H<sub>j</sub>} and M<sub>1</sub> must be initialized as follows:

> i. Initialize the {H<sub>j</sub>} by dividing the 160 bit value t into five 32-bit segments as follows:
>             t = t<sub>0</sub> || t<sub>1</sub> || t<sub>2</sub> || t<sub>3</sub> || t<sub>4</sub>
>       Then H<sub>j</sub> = t<sub>j</sub> for j = 0 through 4.

> ii. There will be only one message block, M<sub>1</sub>, which is initialized as follows: M<sub>1</sub> = c || 0<sup>512-b</sup> (The first b bits of M<sub>1</sub> contain c, and the remaining (512-b) bits are set to zero). Then steps (a) through (e) of section 7 are executed, and G(t,c) is the 160 bit string represented by the five words:
>     H<sub>0</sub> || H<sub>1</sub> || H<sub>2</sub> || H<sub>3</sub> || H<sub>4</sub> at the end of step (e).

Now there's a snag. FIPS186-2, and rfc4187 and rfc4186, refer to an earlier version of the Secure Hash Standard, FIPS180-1 (1995), which has also been superseded, by 180-2 (2002,2004) 180-3 (2008) and 180-4 (2011, 2015), and as far as I can tell is NOT officially archived. But Google finds http://securityv.isu.edu/isl/fip180-1.html whose section 7 a-e are the per-block 'compression function' of SHA-1, matching the substance of 6.1.2 in newer standards though different in notation. The same logic is duplicated, perhaps a little more readably, in [rfc3174 section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3174#section-6.1).

The EAP RFCs specify the initial value of H (now called H<sup>(0)</sup>) is 't' which is the standard initial value for SHA-1 (section 6 in 180-1, 5.3.1 in newer versions), so this amounts to the same thing as SHA-1 for a single-block message EXCEPT WITH DIFFERENT PADDING than defined by 180.

And there's the rub. Implementations of SHA-1 you find in modern systems are almost always designed to do the standard padding, not the zero-padding you need. Unless you can get at the internals -- which will depend on exactly what implementation(s) or platform(s) you use (and that part probably does belong on Stackoverflow where the question was originally posted) -- you'll have to duplicate the code for SHA-1, with this (tiny) modification. Fortunately SHA-1 is used for so many things, and very many of them open source, this shouldn't be too hard; for one possibility, [rfc4634](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4634#section-1.1) (which updates 3174) has C code under a license that (IMOIANAL) is equivalent to CC-BY.